# Creating deformable map in root TCanvas

Tags: c++, plot, root-framework, tcanvas

I have some data that I'm plotting on a TH2F through the command-line interface of ROOT. I have a TTree* called goodtree, and I plot the XY positions of events in a detector as follows:

```
root [1] TCanvas *can = new TCanvas("can","can",800,800)
root [2] goodtree->Draw("y:x>>h1(400,-200,200,400,-200,200)","r<200","colz")
```

I also want to make normalized area plots, by looking at r^2 versus theta:

```
root [3] goodtree->Draw("r*r:t>>h2(400,-3.14,3.14,400,0,41000)","r<200","colz")
```

This part is fine. What I want to do next is overlay a map onto the XY plot, and have it automatically deform to the correct positions on the R^2T plot. What I mean is, this is a particle detector and uses photomultiplier tubes (PMTs) which have a circular cross-section in XY. I want to be able to overlay a map onto h1 which shows the outlines of these PMTs (which are in a honeycomb pattern). *This* I can also do very quickly with a script.

The tough bit is that I want to be able to define this map in XY, and plot it overtop of the R^2T data points. Is there a way do do this easily without having to calculate the positions, widths, and heights of all of these deformed ellipses by hand?

Comment: I guess another way of putting this (more mathematically) would be:

How does one draw a circle with a radius R, centered at an arbitrary point (x, y) = (h, k) in a coordinate system which has r^2 = (x^2 + y^2) on the vertical axis, and theta = tan^-1(y/x) on the horizontal axis?

Comment: I've figured out the math. It's just a coordinate transformation. For a circle centered at (h, k), with a radius R, we have the equation:

    (x-h)^2 + (y-k)^2 = R^2

Since we can also write (x = r*cos(t)) and (y = r*sin(t)), we can substitute these into the above to get

    (r*cos(t)-h)^2 + (r*sin(t)-k)^2 = R^2

Then, if we want to plot t (theta) on the horizontal axis and r^2 on the vertical axis, we let x' = t and y' = r^2 to get

    (sqrt(y)*cos(x)-h)^2 + (sqrt(y)*sin(x)-k)^2 = R^2